# Warning: is_subclass_of() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php, parameters, subclass

My code makes use of `is_subclass_of()`.

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php), there is a third optional parameter, `$allow_string`:

> `bool is_subclass_of ( mixed $object , string $class_name [, bool $allow_string = TRUE ] )`

But the code, which uses a redundant parameter as the third argument in order to make it more explicit, throws an error. Why?

```
class Foo {

  private $fooVar;

}

class Bar extends Foo {

  private $barVar;

}

$fooString = 'Foo';
$barString = 'Bar';

// THE FOLLOWING CODE MAKES $boolVar TRUE,
// but why can't I add the third parameter when the docs say it's allowed?
$boolVar = is_subclass_of($barString, $fooString, true);
// $boolVar = is_subclass_of($barString, $fooString);

if ($boolVar) {
  die("Yes it is. Great!");
} else {
  die("No it isn't. This is not what I want.");
}
```

This is the error message I get:

> Warning:  is_subclass_of() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given on line 18

Comment: Should i guess you have a PHP version(`echo phpversion();`) under: <5.3.9? `Changelog: 5.3.9 Added allow_string parameter` (See: http://3v4l.org/VddvK)

Comment: So were are we now with this question? ^ Was it the php version?

Comment: Not sure, running `phpinfo()` on [this site](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) causes an error, but it could be. Let me check on my local machine...

Comment: This should only print you the php version: `echo phpversion();` just check if it is under 5.3.9

Comment: On my local XAMPP machine, PHP 5.5.3, the code works fine. But [this Test PHP Code Online site](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) where the code was not working also reports PHP 5.3.3 as the version (I've run `echo phpversion();`. So this is strange. What could the problem be?

Comment: `5.3.3` is a older version than `5.3.9`, so your error is just based on a old php version

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The numbers don't match. I will be using [phpfiddle.org](phpfiddle.org) from now on.

Comment: Just adding `ideone.com` and `3v4l.org` <- Which is good to see the different outputs of different php versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine on [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y1rv-n8g5).

See the change log entry on the page you reference:

> 5.3.9     Added allow_string parameter

Are you running an earlier version of PHP? You can check it with

```
echo phpversion();
```